# Installing Istio on GCP Kubernetes - Istio deps Fail

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, istio

I'm following the [tutorial for Istio](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/installing-istio) on the Google Cloud Platform and have been able to get my cluster up and running. I get to part where I start the demo app by running `kubectl apply -f install/kubernetes/istio-demo-auth.yaml` but a number of the pods wont come up.

I'm running Istio 1.0.3

```
kubectl version --short
Client Version: v1.11.1
Server Version: v1.9.7-gke.6
```

When I run the command `kubectl get service -n istio-system`
 to verify istio pods are deployed and containers are running many of them are in crash cycles. Any tips on how to debug this?

```
grafana-7b6d98d887-9dgdc                  1/1       Running             0          17h

istio-citadel-778747b96d-cw78t            1/1       Running             0          17h

istio-cleanup-secrets-2vjlf               0/1       Completed           0          17h

istio-egressgateway-7b8f4ccb6-rl69j       1/1       Running             123        17h

istio-galley-7557f8c985-jp975             0/1       ContainerCreating   0          17h

istio-grafana-post-install-n45x4          0/1       Error               202        17h

istio-ingressgateway-5f94fdc55f-dc2q5     1/1       Running             123        17h

istio-pilot-d6b56bf4d-czp9w               1/2       CrashLoopBackOff    328        17h

istio-policy-6c7d8454b-dpvfj              1/2       CrashLoopBackOff    500        17h

istio-security-post-install-qrzpq         0/1       CrashLoopBackOff    201        17h

istio-sidecar-injector-75cf59b857-z7wbc   0/1       ContainerCreating   0          17h

istio-telemetry-69db5c7575-4jp2d          1/2       CrashLoopBackOff    500        17h

istio-tracing-77f9f94b98-vjmhc            1/1       Running             0          17h

prometheus-67d4988588-gjmcp               1/1       Running             0          17h

servicegraph-57d8ff7686-x2r8r             1/1       Running             0          17h
```

Answer (score 3):

That looks like the output for `kubectl -n istio-system get pods`

Tips, check the output for these:

- `$ kubectl -n istio-system logs istio-pilot-d6b56bf4d-czp9w`
- `$ kubectl -n istio-system logs istio-policy-6c7d8454b-dpvfj`
- `$ kubectl -n istio-system logs istio-grafana-post-install-n45x4`
- `$ kubectl -n istio-system logs istio-telemetry-69db5c7575-4jp2d`
- Check the deployment/service/configmap definitions in `install/kubernetes/istio-demo-auth.yaml` that you have pods crashing for.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing with [Helm via template](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/helm-install/#option-1-install-with-helm-via-helm-template).

You would usually want to have Grafana, Zipkin & Kiali along. This is what worked for me:

1) `kubectl apply -f install/kubernetes/helm/istio/templates/crds.yaml`

2) `helm template install/kubernetes/helm/istio --name istio --namespace istio-system --set grafana.enabled=true --set servicegraph.enabled=true --set tracing.enabled=true --set kiali.enabled=true --set sidecarInjectorWebhook.enabled=true --set global.tag=1.0.5 > $HOME/istio.yaml`

3) `kubectl create namespace istio-system`

4) `kubectl apply -f $HOME/istio.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue - turned out that my NAT Gateway wasn't configured correctly.  The Terraform I used to create the private cluster created an additional default internet gateway that I needed to delete.

Some came up, some didn't - I think that maybe some of the images were cached somewhere the cluster could reach, like a Google repo.